# Splitting text file in Java

Tags: java, arrays, split, text-files

I have a text file which i would like to split. It looks like

```
Julie Resnekov#212#32#90#63.2#62.5
Nathan Sher#378#90#244#90.9#32.5
Jake Reich#772#663#333#67.0#72.0
David Cohen#78#278#67#78.8#72.2
Max Glanz#311#385#89#86.4#88.9
Aaron Burstein#309#112#366#89.5#34.5
Jordan Levin#245#322#90#88.8#85.5
```

I would like to split it along the `hashtags` and then get the split information.

Comment: Go ahead! If you have any problems, let us now.

Comment: If you do a google search, you will find the answer in 10000 milliseconds

Comment: This looks like a (bizarrely formed) CSV, so you can use OpenCSV to do the job

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in learning something,

*Following Steps will help you.*

- First of all Use `BufferReader` to read file
- Read one line at time by the use of `readLine()` and store it to `String`
- Now your `String` will have  line i.e`Julie Resnekov#212#32#90#63.2#62.5`
- Use [split()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) method to split  the `String` content by `#`
- Now you will have array of `String` which is retrived after split.

Otherwise <kbd>COPY</kbd>+<kbd>PASTE</kbd> is the second option.

Answer (score 0):

Use split method

```
String string = "Julie Resnekov#212#32#90#63.2#62.5";
String[] parts = string.split("#");

for(String part : parts){
System.out.println(part);
}
```

Comment: What about other parts?

Comment: @AnkurShanbhag I have Edited

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] split = info.split("#");
```

In your case this would yield an array containing the name in `split[0]` and the numbers in the rest of the array.